# how to solve Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ResumeAfter<string>' when authenticated in c#.net code

Tags: c#, .net, azure, graph, bots

trying to retrive  useremail id after user authenticated, But it gives error at ResumeAfterAuth in authentication method 
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ResumeAfter'
How to solve it? 
Authentication code

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
{
    var message = await item;
     //endpoint v1
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(await context.GetAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"])))
    {
       //Navigate to website for Login
       await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"]), ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

After authentication method

```
private async Task ResumeAfterAuth(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<AuthResult> result)
{
    //AD resposnse message
    var message = await result;
    string tokenstring = message.AccessToken;
    string userName = message.UserName;
    await context.PostAsync("Welcome to BOT");
    await context.PostAsync(message.ToString());
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

Comment: It is really important to include everything in your question. For example, an important part you left out is that you are using BotFramework v3. Consider moving to v4 please, as it is not supprted anymore. Also, what is the result of the AzureAuthDialog? Is it a IDialog<AuthResult>?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a mismatch between in your arguments. Make sure that your AzureAuthDialog is of type IDialog, or change the ResumeAfterAuth method to expect a 
`IAwaitable<type that matches the AzureAuthDialog>`

Also, while your project is still fresh, please consider migrating to BotFrameworkv4, as v3.0 is not supported anymore.